# Application Defined or Object Defined Error in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

VBE points to this bit of code which is causing the error:

```
Sheets("Topology").Range(Me.Get_Cell_Location).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

The whole function is defined as follows:

```
Public Function Colour_Me(choice As Integer) As Boolean

If choice = 1 Then

    Debug.Print "Choice 1"

     If Me.Get_Enabled1 = True Or Me.Get_Enabled2 = True Or Me.Get_Enabled3 = True Then
        Sheets("Topology").Range(Me.Get_Cell_Location).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Colour_Me = True
     Else
        Sheets("Topology").Range(Me.Get_Cell_Location).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Colour_Me = False
     End If

ElseIf choice = 2 Then

      Debug.Print "Choice 2"

     If Me.Get_Enabled1 = True Or Me.Get_Enabled2 = True Or Me.Get_Enabled3 = True Then
        Sheets("Topology").Range(Me.Get_Cell_Location).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Colour_Me = True
     Else
        Sheets("Topology").Range(Me.Get_Cell_Location).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Colour_Me = False
     End If
End If

End Function
```

The code in choice 1 seems to work alright, but choice 2 is giving me problems.

**UPDATE**

```
Public Property Let Set_Cell_Location(location As String)
    cell_location = location
End Property

Public Property Get Get_Cell_Location()
    Get_Cell_Location = cell_location
End Property
```

Comment: `Colour_Me` is the method name, not a variable, right? I'm not fluent with VB but it seems like instead you'd want to create a Boolean variable and set it to true or false depending on the result, then return that variable to the caller.

Comment: Get_Cell_Location is a sub whose value is supposed to be a string (ex. A3)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting that error because Excel is not able to determine the range. I have introduced error handling and added a MSGBOX. See what value does it give you?

Try this

```
Public Function Colour_Me(choice As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Rng As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set Rng = Sheets("Topology").Range(Me.Get_Cell_Location)

    If choice = 1 Then
        Debug.Print "Choice 1"
        If Me.Get_Enabled1 = True Or Me.Get_Enabled2 = True Or _
        Me.Get_Enabled3 = True Then
           Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
           Colour_Me = True
        Else
           Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
           Colour_Me = False
        End If
    ElseIf choice = 2 Then
        Debug.Print "Choice 2"
        If Me.Get_Enabled1 = True Or Me.Get_Enabled2 = True Or _
        Me.Get_Enabled3 = True Then
           Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
           Colour_Me = True
        Else
           Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
           Colour_Me = False
        End If
    End If
    Exit Function
Whoa:
    '~~> I have just put this here for testing
    Msgbox Me.Get_Cell_Location
End Function
```

Comment: the MSGBOX comes up with no text. I guess Me.Get_Cell_Location doesn't have a value before the sub call? hm...

Comment: Is `Get_Cell_Location` a Sub or a Function? How are you calling `Get_Cell_Location`? Maybe you would like to include the value as one of the parameters of the function? For example `Colour_Me(choice As Integer, Addr as String)`

Comment: Ok, this might be the problem: I put `Debug.Print Me.Get_Cell_Location` in the beginning of the function, and in the immediate window it says $J$9 instead of J9.

Comment: Not the $ will not give you a problem. Can you confirm if `Get_Cell_Location` a Sub or a Function

Comment: Nvm Siddharth, I figured out what was wrong. I didn't initialize the class from which Get_Cell_Location was trying to access from.

Comment: So I was right :) The value of the `Me.Get_Cell_Location` didn't have a value because of which it showed you a blank message and hence the Range was failing